# Missing library: xdoclet-1.2.3.jar. Select the home directory for XDoclet. 1.2.3

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently converted an eclipse java project to be a `dynamic web project` by opening up `project facets` and selecting `dynamic web module with xdoclets`.  However, I get the following error in the project.

```
The preferences for the XDoclet runtime does not point to a valid installation.
```

Googling this error seems to indicate that `xdoclets` need to be configured for the workspace or eclipse installation and not just for the project, so I  opened `Window > Preferences > JavaEE > XDoclet`, and found the following warning:

```
Missing library: xdoclet-1.2.3.jar. Select the home directory for XDoclet. 1.2.3
```

Most of the google results for this are 8 to 10 years old.  **Do I even need XDoclets enabled?  Why does eclipse set XDoclets as a default for Dynamic Web Modules if all the documentation is almost a decade old?**

**How can I resolve this error?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [why this eclipse error showing and what should be the solution for it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737968/why-this-eclipse-error-showing-and-what-should-be-the-solution-for-it)